# How to find current and voltage requirements of an LED lamp / strip using a multimeter?

Tags: led, current-measurement, voltage-measurement, led-strip, led-driver

I have an LED lamp who's current and voltage ratings aren't written on the lamp itself. How do I find the required input current and voltage to this lamp before powering it, using for example a multimeter?

For context: I have an LED driver that produces voltages between 100 and 300 volts at a current of between 0.3 and 0.7 amps. I want to make sure that the lamp I am using with this driver doesn't require a voltage and current that is out of this range (either greater than or less the range provided) but I don't have access to the tech sheet. How would I do this?

Comment: You can't do that.

Comment: Why not? What tools do I need to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach the LED lamp to a power supply and ramp up the voltage until it is acceptable bright. Record the voltage and current. That is your new rating.

You can't tell the actual rating with knowing the ratings of the parts inside and how they are connected. The packaging can even influence the rating if it can't keep the parts cool.